# C program works only a part

Tags: c

I need to make a program which says that I have to fill "1" in the odd rows and "0" in the even ones. I tried and wrote this code, but it seem like it works for only a part. 
Please, can you explain me the method?

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

main()
{
  int r, c;
  do {
  printf("Insert the number of the rows in the matrix: ");
  scanf("%d", &r);
  printf("Insert the number of the colums in the matrix: ");
  scanf("%d", &c);
  } while(r<=0||c<=0);

  r--; c--;
  int mat[r][c];
  int a, b;

  for(a=0; a<=r; a++)
  {
    for(b=0; b<=c; b++)
    {
      if(a%2==0)
      {mat[a][b]=0;}
      else {mat[a][b]=1;}
    }
  }

  printf("\nOUTPUT:\n\n");
    for(a=0; a<=r; a++){
      for(b=0; b<=c; b++){
        printf("%d", mat[a][b]);
      }
      printf("\n");
    }

  return 0;
}
```

INPUT: 2, 3

OUTPUT: 
001
111

Comment: `(r<=0||c<=0)` should be `(r<=0 && c<=0)`

Comment: `for(a=0; a<=r; a++)` should be `a < r`, same problem everywhere.

Comment: I have the impression that you have written this code but you don't know how to debug it. This can be done in two ways: either you use a debugging tool (which usually comes along the program you're using to write this code), or you temporarily put some debugging "printf()" commands in order to follow what's happening, like `print("a=[%d]\n",a); // comment` when you want to follow how the value of `a` is changing through your program.

Comment: On a side note: In this special case you have here instead of writing `if(a%2==0){mat[a][b]=0;}else{mat[a][b]=1;}` you can write just `mat[a][b] = a%2;`. If you want to work it with arbitrary values instead of modulo 2 and get values 0 and 1 you can write `mat[a][b] = !!(a%n);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't use the number of rows and columns correctly. It is true that in C, an array with `N` entries can access the indices 0 through `N - 1` only and that the index `N` is one beyond the range of the array. But you still have to define the array with the actual size:

```
// Don't adjust c and r here

int mat[r][c];
```

When you use the dimension in a `for` loop, you can ensure that you never access `mat[r][c]` by using `<` instead of `<=` as condition:

```
for (a = 0; a < r; a++) {
    for (b = 0; b < c; b++) {
        if (a % 2 == 0) {
            mat[a][b] = 0;
        } else {
            mat[a][b] = 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are messing up with the size of the matrix. You might want to change the sequence of these two and give it a try :

```
r--; c--;
int mat[r][c];
```

change this to

```
int mat[r][c];
r--; c--;
```

and the code should work as you expect.